# powerful VPS but slow MS SQL- why?

Tags: sql-server, performance, performance-tuning

VPS ([Contabo](https://contabo.com/?show=configurator&vserver_id=245)) : 10 cores (Xeon E5 2.2GHz), 60 GB RAM, SSD, MS SQL Web Edition (configured to use 10 CPUs), Windows Server 2016
When running SQL takes ~32GB of RAM,

When I execute SQL a stored procedure (CPU~19%, Disk 1MB read, 05.MB write) it is slower than on my laptop (i7,16 GB ram,SSD and SQL Express....).

What is wrong? How to improve performances on my VPS?

Comment: You're running a VPS vs dedicated hardware - why would you expect it to be faster?

Comment: Start by [getting execution plans](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/) for both environments.

Comment: Contabo guarantees resources (even if they are shared) on VPS so i'm not getting why VPS must be slower.

Comment: You are still sharing the CPU, PCI & memory buses etc with the other tenants on the server. Also, just because your data is on a [fast] SSD does not guarantee you the IOPS as it's shared

Comment: also ssd vs SSD could be "very different", in any case advice above about plans is good to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SQL a stored procedure (CPU~19%, Disk 1MB read, 05.MB write) it is slower than on my laptop (i7,16 GB ram,SSD and SQL Express....).

Probably because your laptop is faster than your server.

Many i7s are significantly faster than a 2.2Ghz Xeon for single-threaded operations.  And not all "SSD" drives are the same.  The flash storage devices on modern laptops can be much faster than what might be used by your hoster.

The Xeon has more cores, and so can perform more work *overall*.  So a realistic load test should show that the server can support more concurrent users.  But for a single user, you shouldn't expect the server to be faster

> How to improve performances on my VPS?

So that's normal SQL Server performance analysis and optimization.  Good news is that you can do the testing and optimization work on your laptop :)